# UI Design Concepts in WinForms

Tags: winforms

In one certain case I want to disable the tabpannel so that the controlls in the tab panel are disabled.

I want to disable the tab pannel but still I want ennable the controls in tab pannel.the need is User cannot switch over to the annother tabpannel in a certain senerio.

How can I do this requirement?.

by 
dinesh

Answer (score 1):

Use something besides a tab panel.

It is not standard behavior for a tab panel to have one tab "stuck" so that the user cannot move to the other tabs. You're going to throw users off if you do this.

What you are after sounds like a modal dialog. It sounds like you don't want the users to move away from a certain screen until they're doing entering some data or some such. The modal dialog is built for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to disable Tab Page, only you can remove it. But in your case, you can't remove the Tab, So I think you need to put some code in the Tab_SelectionIndex change event. And when ever the Tab index comes, set it back to another one.

Try this code

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to anuraj's answer, set the colour of the tab text to the disabled text colour state, so it is a visual cue it is "disabled".